# Preserving the <br> tags when cleaning with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

For the input text:

```
<p>Arbit string <b>of</b><br><br>text. <em>What</em> to <strong>do</strong> with it?
```

I run the following code:

```
Whitelist list = Whitelist.simpleText().addTags("br");
// Some other code...
// plaintext is the string shown above
retVal = Jsoup.clean(plaintext, StringUtils.EMPTY, list,
            new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
```

I get the output:

```
Arbit string <b>of</b>

text. <em>What</em> to <strong>do</strong> with it?
```

I don't want Jsoup to convert the `<br>` tags to line breaks, I want to keep them as-is. How can I do that?

Comment: If your question is sufficiently answered, you should consider accepting the best answer and thereby mark this question as solved. If you need further help, please specify exactly what you need help with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Document doc2deal = Jsoup.parse(inputText);
doc2deal.select("br").append("br"); //or append("<br>")
```

Comment: @markvgti please check the answer you think it was helpful to solve your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not reproducible for me. Using Jsoup 1.8.3 and this code:

```
String html = "<p>Arbit string <b>of</b><br><br>text. <em>What</em> to <strong>do</strong> with it?";
String cleaned = Jsoup.clean(html, 
        "", 
        Whitelist.simpleText().addTags("br"),
        new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
System.out.println(cleaned);
```

I get the following output:

```
Arbit string <b>of</b><br><br>text. <em>What</em> to <strong>do</strong> with it?
```

Your problem must be somewhere else I guess.